# How to view Arena Chess analysis in a chess program?

Tags: analysis, arena

I made an analysis of a chess game in Arena Chess with stockfish engine. The analysis completed successfully. My question is how can I watch this analysis in a chess program.

Arena chess says it made the analysis output to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arena\Analysis.log file.`

But I am not able to view this file in any chess program (including Arena chess).

The content of the above mentioned file looked like this:

```
8. Ra1-c1             
    Best move (Stockfish_20090216_x64): Qd1-b3
    Not found in: 00:04
   21-12-2020 18:42:31, Time for this analysis: 00:00:04, Rated time: 00:30
8. ..Bc8-d7           
    Best move (Stockfish_20090216_x64): a2-a3
    Not found in: 00:04
   21-12-2020 18:42:39, Time for this analysis: 00:00:04, Rated time: 00:34
9. c4xd5              
    Best move (Stockfish_20090216_x64): a2-a3
    Not found in: 00:04
   21-12-2020 18:42:48, Time for this analysis: 00:00:04, Rated time: 00:38
9. ..e6xd5            
    Best move (Stockfish_20090216_x64): a2-a3
    Not found in: 00:04
    30/38-  00:45        27,081k    593k    -0.19   
   21-12-2020 18:42:56, Time for this analysis: 00:00:04, Rated time: 00:42
```

How can I open this file in a chess program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [log file](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5445/log-file) and can't be parsed. You can view the results in the GUI after the analysis has finished; then you can save the game as PGN (so that it can be parsed by Arena). You can do this by clicking PGN → Save current game in PGN format.

Comment: Hi, I completed an analysis for moves 9-11. After sometime, it says, analysis completed successfully. But nothing new is written in the gui window. Gui shows the original moves only. No variation nothing is written new. Can you please check?

Comment: @JanetMThomas right-click → display → make sure all the boxes are ticked.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is showing analysis results in green font. But the problem is clicking on those green font, nothing happens. I see the analysis are saved as a commentary. Not as variation. Do you know how to make the analysis moves as variation in the pgn file?

Comment: Do you know how to convert commentary into variation?

Comment: @JanetMThomas editing the PGN file manually is a solution, but it will probably take too much time.